# csv to json integer parse error using placeholders

Tags: json, csv, automated-tests, karate, karate-call-single

so i have one csv file from there i'm parsing data in json, but there is integer conversion issue.

- def foo = '10'
- string json = { bar: '#(1 * foo)' }
- match json == '{"bar":10.0}'
- string json = { bar: '#(parseInt(foo))' }
- match json == '{"bar":10.0}'

so i tried both ways to convert an string into integer but i am getting below error message:
"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "(1 * total_amount)": not a valid `java.lang.Integer` value".
And 1000 is the value i'm giving in a csv file.

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.karateauto</groupId>
<artifactId>Karate-Lead_Demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.11.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0</maven.surefire.version>
    <karate.version>1.4.1</karate.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <classifier>all</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Above is my pom file.

{
"action": "#(action)",
"currency": "#(currency)",
"cptrid": "#(cptrid)",
"flexi1": "#(flexi1)",
"flexi2": "#(flexi2)",
"flexi3": "#(flexi3)",
"flexi4": "#(flexi4)",
"sys_id": "#(sys_id)",
"lead_id": "#(lead_id)",
"record_id": "#(record_id)",
"mode_of_payment": "#(mode_of_payment)",
"total_amount": "#(1 * total_amount)",
"instrument_ref": "#(instrument_ref)",
"instrument_date": "#(instrument_date)",
"bank_name": "#(bank_name)",
"branch_detls": "#(branch_detls)",
"receipt_no": "#(receipt_no)"
}

and above is the way i'm using placeholder for total amount.

Answer (score 1):

```
Feature: Integer parsing feature

  Scenario Outline: Integer parsing scenario
    Given url 'https://reqres.in/api/users'
    And request {"name":'#(name)',"job":'#(parseInt(job))'}
    When method post
    Then status 201

    Examples: 
      | read('classpath:testdata/create_post_testdata.csv').slice(0, 2) |
```

csv file:

```
name,job
Json-server1,1
Json-server2,2
```

Comment: what if request is too complex and big.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following and it worked perfectly in Karate 1.4.1

```
* def foo = '10'
* string json = { bar: '#(1 * foo)' }
* match json == '{"bar":10}'
* string json = { bar: '#(parseInt(foo))' }
* match json == '{"bar":10}'
```

You have something else going on then, so follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: <karate.version>1.4.1</karate.version>, i'm also using same version.

Comment: @sagarkapde nothing else anyone can do. follow this process please: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: it's an json issue ,
{
  "mode_of_payment": "#(mode_of_payment)",
  "total_amount" : "#(total_amount)",
  "instrument_ref": "#(instrument_ref)",
  "instrument_date": "#(instrument_date)",
  "bank_name": "#(bank_name)",
  "branch_detls": "#(branch_detls)",
  "receipt_no": "#(receipt_no)"
}
in json request i want to pass total_amount as integer, but karate feature file is taking it as a string. so it's giving this issue "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String \"$(total_amount)\": not a valid `java.lang.Integer`"

Comment: @sagarkapde I have nothing to add to my previous comments